# Sequence of finder methods in Active Record Query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am writing a complex Active record query to fetch data from multiple tables, the query have joins , select , order , group ,select where.

```
         @posts = Post.published.paginate(:order => 'popularity desc, id',
                                          :joins => [:comments, :images, :updates, :user],
                                          :conditions => conditions,
                                          :group => "posts.id",
                                          :select => "posts.id*,
                                          :per_page => 10, 
                                          :page => params[:page])
```

I wanted to know what should be the sequence of where , joins etc as per the standard and to maximize the performance of the query. If someone could write a query to explain the sequence that would be really great like

```
@posts = Post.published.joins(:comments, :images, :updates, :user).where(....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the sequence does not matter.

An example would be:

```
@posts = Post.published.select('posts.id').
  joins(:comments, :images, :updates, :user).
  where('users.email = ?', 'john@doe.com').
  group('posts.id')
```